# Designing a down counter using Xilinx ISE design

Tags: counter

We are trying to design a circuit that counts down from 9.99 to 0.00. Could you give us some tips?

Comment: At which level do you want to write your HDL code? For me, it'll be easier to decrement from 999, and then place a fixed point `.` at the output stage.

Comment: we arent using vhdl. we are using schematic design.

Comment: Please edit your question to give all the information that's needed to provide you with a useful answer.